# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2(netbeans)

Tags: maven, netbeans, pom.xml

[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project test1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Spa.png)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you use a quite recent version of java to execute your build and I suspect that the plugin version of `maven-war-plugin` does not support java modules.

So in order to get this work I think all you need is to update your `maven-war-plugin` version to a more recent one like `3.3.2`.